# How can I display my search results?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, search

I've have alot of code, see my website here -> http://code-programmersplace.rhcloud.com/

I have decided I want to add search box. So I have created a class for it: `search.java`.
Now I want to show a search result, but the problem is that I have alot of code. So how do I show the filtered result?..

Should I show the html code from the class or just go to a new page, like `search.jsp`?

I'm so confused! Please help!

***Edited:***

I'm trying to make this:

```
package com.search;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class search extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

        String search_name=request.getParameter("search_name");

        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        out.println("<!DOCTYPE>"
                + "<html>"
                + "<head>"
                + "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>"
                + "<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700|Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>"
                + "<title>Search - "+search_name+"</title>"
                + "");
    }
}
```

I have alot of header files, fonts and etc.. So should i just show it a class... Or should i just create a another page for it?

Comment: Showing us some code would also be appreciated.

Comment: create another page , and pass anything you want to that page

Answer (score 0):

You should use the MVC approach

In short, MVC stands for: Model - View - Control

So, your buissness logic goes in your servlet ( The controller ) 
Afterwards, send the

```
String search_name=request.getParameter("search_name");
```

into your session object like this for instance

```
req.getSession.setAttribute("Search", search_name);
```

Create a new JSP page , for this example lets call it temp.jsp

Then, call the request dispatcher:

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/temp.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

At this stage, you are now at your JSP.

From your JSP, get the search term:

```
<% String term = (String)session.getAttribute("Search"); %>
```

And from here, do whatever you wish to do with your term.

If you want to query a databse etc, you need to create a model for it, then call it from the controller, and then forward it to the view  -> JSP.

Implementing MVC will make your life much easier.

Happy coding!